# How to run JavaScript using jsc on OS X?

Tags: javascript, macos, webkit

I got [this](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JSC) when I was trying to find some way to run my JavaScript programs through terminal. The `run` and `load` command mentioned can execute external JavaScript files. Help me how to do this. I am trying to run JavaScript programs which are store locally on my system.

**EDIT**: I am trying to solve Project Euler Q10 in JavaScript. So this is the program that I want to run in NodeJs or JSC. I need help in running the JavaScript files in Node and JSC.
Any example will be really helpful.

Thank You all.

Comment: The instructions you link to seem clear enough. What problem are you having? What are you trying? How does the behaviour you get differ from the behaviour you expect?

Answer (score 82):

Complements of [this post](http://www.phpied.com/javascript-shell-scripting/), JSC lives at

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/jsc
```

and is not in the shell `PATH` by default.  You can fix that with

```
ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/jsc /usr/local/bin
```

`jsc` takes filenames as arguments.  You could run a file named `demo.js` with

```
jsc demo.js
```

Note that you'll have to use `debug()` instead of the conventional `console.log()` in your script to see any output.

Comment: On OSX El Capitan I needed to use `ln -s` for this to work.

Comment: I found my `jsc` with `find /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework -iname jsc` - it seems to move around a lot.

Answer (score 14):

**NOTE for MacOS Catalina (10.15.x) users**

`jsc` now lives on a new path:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Helpers/jsc
```

Make that adjustment to @hurrymaplelad's instructions and you'll be good to go.

Comment: `ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Helpers/jsc /usr/local/bin` and then from my home dir: `jsc -h` and I get `-bash: jsc: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

You're not very clear on what sort of programs these scripts are. Do they do local tasks (e.g. interact with the local file system)? Or are they web scripts that are supposed to interact with (HT|X)ML documents?

If your usage scenario is the former, I recommend using [node.js](http://nodejs.org). It is under heavy development, but it is already very usable. For my first project with Node I wrote an XMPP chat bot, completely in JavaScript.

**Edit:**

I seem to have overlooked "using jsc" in the question and answered "How to run JavaScript on OS X?" instead. Still, I think Node is a better alternative if the author is looking to use JavaScript in place of something like Python or Perl.

Answer (score -1):

For future reference: I made a GitHub gist with updated info on using JSC, is available [here](https://gist.github.com/ctkjose/03d14236a55c4b85cb8d6e6156c57b13).