# Run Javascript file from command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, console.log

I have a javascript file hello.js with `console.log("Hello World")`. I want to run it from my terminal (I am on a mac). I have node installed and I take the following steps -

1. Open terminal and navigate to the directory where hello.js exists.
2. Run command "node hello.js"

But I dont see the console statement (Hello World) in my terminal.

Can some one please help me run javascript from terminal (or tell me what I am doing wrong) ?

PS: I have checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659778/is-it-possible-to-run-javascript-files-from-the-command-line) but my problem still exists.

Comment: So when you type `node hello.js` you get no error, nothing at all from your terminal.?

Comment: Are you sure you have node installed?  You can double check that node is installed by doing `node -v` to get its version. Are you absolutely certain you are in the correct directory before running `node hello.js`?

Comment: What is your output if you run `node -v`

Comment: my node -v gives me "v8.2.1"

Comment: and no i don't get any errors when i run "node hello.js" .. the code does seem to run for a while (the terminal window kind of freezes for a second) but there is no output

Comment: What does running `cat hello.js` output?

Comment: `cat hello.js` output is `console.log("Hello World")`

Comment: does `node hello.js` output anything, at all?

Comment: Check `which node` as well...

Comment: Is your `node` command bind as alias for other thing?

Comment: @TomaszBubała - no there is no output

Comment: @Zooly - i dont think so

Comment: If you just installed node via NPM,  you should probably restart your computer before trying to run a JS file.

Comment: echo "console.log('Hello World');" | node

Answer (score 2):

One possible error is that your JavaScript file doesn't end with a new line character.

The node parser will read the last line, but it won't completely process the line unless it includes a new line marker (or, possibly, a semicolon).

Make sure your file includes the new line (as well as, preferably, a semicolon), i.e.:

```
console.log("Hello World");
// EOF comment, to validate a new line marker after last line of code.
```

This **might** solve your issue - unless the reason for your issue lies somewhere else.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to first accurately create the path to the .js file. This is probably your problem.

When you first open the CLI (Command Line) there will be a path displayed.
For example...

C:\Users\yourname>

from there you have to get to where the file is located, so you type in..
C:\Users\yourname>cd\Users\yourname\Documents\course\jsfolder

cd means "change directory"..and just put the full path to where the file is located.

Now to see if you are there by typing dir on the end

C:\Users\yourname>\Documents\course\jsfolder>dir

This will list all the files in that last directory. You should see your New.js file in there. You are now ready to go!

Follow what Anupam said above...type.. node New.js  ..and your file will run if you have node.js installed on your computer..BINGO!>

one last thing ..I believe the command "node" is "$node" on an Apple

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

There are a few additional solutions you could use other than node.

The expected behavior of node would be to print "Hello World" for you, and there has been help troubleshooting in the comments of your post.

**jsc** is included with macOS. You should make a link to the file first as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7357819), and change your `console.log()` methods to `debug()`.

**rhino** is available from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Download_Rhino). It would require you to switch your `console.log()` methods to `print()`.

For installing rhino, you may be able to avoid some of the issues you've had with node by installing through [homebrew](https://brew.sh). As a last means of troubleshooting node, you may also find it useful to reinstall it through homebrew.

Answer (score -1):

You can Run your JavaScript File from your Terminal only if you have installed NodeJs runtime. If you have Installed it then Simply open the terminal and type “node FileName.js”.

1. Open Terminal or Command Prompt.
2. Set Path to where File is Located (using cd).
3. Type “node New.js” and Click Enter

Comment: this is not helping, this is exactly what the thread-opener already tried.